# How to make JTextField as wide as the window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I want to make the text automatically as wide as the window. I tried using `text.setSize(window.getWidth(),20)` and `text.setBounds(window.getWidth(),20)`, (where text is JTextfield), but the only way that seems to work is: `static JTextField text = new JTextField(int numberOfColumns);` I'm using GridBag layout.

Comment: Don't set the size but use an apropriate layout. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55024689/3992939

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: I have edited example according to GridBagLayout.

Use layout manager. It will automatically expands component according to window. 
For example;

```
Jpanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.gridx = 0;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
panel.add(textfield,c);
```

Comment: I think i forgot to mention, that I'm using GridBag layout. I don't know whether that makes a difference

Comment: Yes, it makes a _huge_ difference!  In the `GridBagConstraints` for your field, set the `gridx` to 0, the  `gridwidth` to `GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER and `fill` to `GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL` or `GridBagConstraints.BOTH`